# Efficient way to compute the $L^1$ norm of quantum state

Tags: swap-test, hadamard-test

We all know that the $L^2$ norm

$$
||\psi||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_i |c_i|^2}
$$

of a quantum state $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i c_i |i\rangle$ is always equal to $1$. It is possible to compute the $L^1$ norm

$$
||\psi||_1 = \sum_i |c_i|
$$

by brute force by simply executing the circuit and then summing the square roots of the obtain probabilities associated with each element of the computational basis.

I was wondering if there is some faster way to do that, maybe using an ancilla.

Extra: is there any way to estimate $\sum_i c_i$?

Comment: In terms of the "extra", then it depends on exactly what you want. Technically, $\sum_ic_i$ is not well defined due to the possibility of a global phase. However, it is possible to estimate something like $\left|\sum_ic_i\right|^2$. You do this just by running a swap test between your state and $\sum_i|i\rangle$.

Comment: Oh that would be perfect as well. Is the state $\sum_i |i\rangle$ obtained by simply applying Hadamard to each qubit? (I think there is a normalization factor missing, right?)

Comment: Yes, that's right. And yes, I was being lazy about normalisation factors. So this means that when you do the swap test, there's a small multiplier, meaning that you have to repeat things a lot to get an accurate answer.